# Angular app restarting every time there is a submission to json server

Tags: angular, json-server

Suddenly, out of nowhere, without anything modified or updated, every time I press a button to submit some data to my app's fake backend database (`json server API`) the page re-loads.

This happens on **Chrome** and **Firefox** and **Edge**.

I looked around and found some suggestions (e.g. [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19431)) for changing the for submission button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` but this does not work for me, because then my form data is not submitted.

Is there a way to programmatically do this? Has anyone come across this lately?

p.s. For now, I am not 'watching' my 'db.json' as a workaround to avoid this issue, but I have to fix it to be able to have my `json server API` running...

**EDIT**

This is my `form` code:

```
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAnnotateSelection(postForm.value)">

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="chosenTitle" rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a title for your annotation here..."
                [(ngModel)]="chosenTitle">
            </textarea>

            <textarea name="highlightedText" id="selectedText" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Your highlighted text will appear here..."
                [(ngModel)]="highlightedText" (mouseup)="mouseUp()">
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!postForm.valid">
            Annotate your highlighted/selected Text
        </button>

        <a class="btn btn-secondary active" role="button" [href]="fileUrl" download="annotations.txt">
            Download All Annotations
        </a>

</form>
```

This code was fine. I doubt that there is something in the form code. I suspect something in my `package-lock.json` changes, because this lock file used to be in my `gitignore` file, then I learned that it should actually be under version control, so I did so. Could it have anything to do with changes in the lock file at all?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the form controls? Can you include a template snippet (are you using reactive forms, or template driven)?

Comment: 10$ your form is wrapped by an additional `<form>` tag (are you hosting it on a 3rd party website ?) please add the template between your top most `<form>` tags.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Thanks for your reply. It's template driven. My submission is `<button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!postForm.valid"> Annotate your highlighted/selected Text </button>`  I will post my form as an edit to the question...

Comment: @Stavm How do I get my 10$?  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop submitting the form and use

```html
<button
  class="btn btn-outline-success"
  type="button"
  [disabled]="!postForm.valid"
  (click)="onAnnotateSelection(postForm.value)">
  Annotate your highlighted/selected
</button>
```

You should also remove the `ngSubmit` from the `form` element.